# Canada's polymer $100 bank notes: When will other dollar amounts of "plastic money" be available?

Tags: canada, currency, paper-money

In November 2011, the Bank of Canada released a new *polymer* (plastic) one-hundred dollar bank note, including transparent areas and metallic images.

What other denominations of Canadian paper money will be made available in polymer, and when?

When will the old paper notes be phased out of circulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Press release titled
 [Bank of Canada Issues $100 Bill – First Canadian Polymer Bank Note](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/2011/11/press-releases/bank-canada-issues-100-bill-first-canadian-polymer-bank-note/)

The $50 note, which was also unveiled in June, will be issued in March 2012. The $20 note will begin circulating in late 2012, followed by the $10 and $5 notes by the end of 2013. Detailed images of the notes and information on their designs will be released on their official unveiling dates.